# do-release-upgrade -d does not offer up 16.04 on a fully updated Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

This command has worked just fine on a couple of Lubuntu systems.  But, the first time I tried it on an Ubuntu system, no joy.

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
[sudo] password for xxxxxx: 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

What did I leave out?

Edit -------------------------------

After doing Michael Krell's suggestion of
`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Now when I issue the command `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` I get

```
Err Upgrade tool signature                                                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]                                         
Err Upgrade tool                                                               
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]                                         
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      
WARNING:root:file 'utopic.tar.gz.gpg' missing
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.
```

Comment: @OrganicMarble the `-d` option is for the developtment branch, try what output you get if you do `do-release-upgrade -c` for checking the normal branch.

Comment: @Videonauth if I use the `-c` option it offers up 15.10

Comment: and from there then to 16.04 the normal way to go if you dont want to wait the first point release.

Comment: Thanks! But why did it allow me to go straight to 16.04 on the Lubuntu systems?

Comment: To be honest, i have no clue why. MAybe the poster of an answer here wants to incooperate this all into his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now.  I can only assume there was some problem on the Ubuntu server side.